# Variable loses its watcher when filter is applied

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to implement a calendar component in AngularJS, but I've stumbled upon a bug when trying to display the current month. In my components controller I have the following:

```
this.date = new Date();
this.month = this.date.getMonth() + 1;
```

which I'm using in my template as:

```
<span class="picker-nav" ng-click="$ctrl.prevMonth()"><</span>
   {{$ctrl.month | date: 'MMMM'}}
<span class="picker-nav" ng-click="$ctrl.nextMonth()">></span>
```

When I click on either of the spans it doesnt change the months name as it should. But, if I dont include the filter, it works as expected, without the date formating. My guess is that the filter does something so the variable isnt being watched for changes, therefor is there any way I can make this work without having to manually set up a `$watch` ?

Comment: Can you share your `$ctrl.nextMonth()` and `$ctrl.prevMonth()` methods?

Comment: `this.month` is an integer, not   a date. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @TsvetanGanev the two methods increment and decrement by 1 the month being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Discard `this.month = this.date.getMonth() + 1` from your code and format the date using the filter. Integers cannot be watched because they are fundamental types, not objects.

Comment: The issue is that the two methods I'm using increment or decrement the month being displayed. So the month ultimately has to be an integer.

Comment: Change just the month of the Date value, see [setMonth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/setmonth-method-date-javascript).